# Python context manager

Tags: python

Trying to use my little method but I get follow error:

```
class mycls:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __enter__(self):
        ...

    def little(self):
        ...

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        ...


with mycls() as cl:
    cl.little()
    with cl:
        cl.little()
        with cl:
            cl.little()
    cl.little()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'little'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `with` statement does not bind the instance of `mycls` itself to `cl`, but rather the return value of that instance's `__enter__` method. Currently, `mycls.__enter__` returns `None`, hence the observed error. Change `__enter__` to

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self
```

and your code should work as expected.

Code like

```
with foo as bar:
    ...
```

is (ignoring a lot of details) roughly the same as

```
x = foo()
bar = x.__enter__()
...
x.__exit__()
```

Comment: Just to note, it's not that you have to return `self`, but whatever you return will be bound.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return `self` from `__enter__`:

```
class mycls:
   def __enter__(self):
      return self
   def __exit__(self, *_):
      pass
   def little(self):
      pass

with mycls() as cl:
   cl.little()
   with cl:
      cl.little()
      with cl:
         cl.little()
   cl.little()
```